# Pycharm: Detected doubious ownership in repository error

Tags: git, pycharm

I have issue with Pycharm. I have it connected with my WSL and yesterday I moved WSL to another drive because of space. Today I started Pycharm and have this error:

`Error updating changes: detected dubious ownership in repository at '...' To add an exception for this directory, call: git config --global --add safe.directory`

I searched the web for some solution. I tried the command which is displayed in the error but that didn't help either. I've also tried to clear the cache in Pycharm and restart it. But what is weird is that from the terminal it works. I can commit and push but the error in Pycharm still persist.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you paste that text as _text_ in the question? (wanted to make a joke about sending me an electronic microscope but I realized it would not be constructive).

Comment: Error updating changes: detected dubious ownership in repository at '...' To add an exception for this directory, call: git config --global --add safe.directory ...

(About the joke... Good one but you know that you can click the picture to see it bigger?)

Comment: I know, but it is _better_ if you put the text there because it might be found by other people with the same problem.

Comment: That error is a check that was added rather recently to git to avoid a possible attack vector.

Comment: That command that is displayed there is imcomplete, by the way, you need to provide the _path_  (a full path... understandable to git, I would assume... so if you are working on Windows, I would _suggest_ to be careful about the casing of the path... though I have no idea of how it should work on WSL) so that it could work. The other thing you might try is to make sure that the user under which the git process is running there is the owner of the whole repo.